# How to make an ImageView "match_parent"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

How can I get the bottom image (the white box) to fill the entire width of the view? I have tried dragging it and match_parent but still no luck. The bottom corners of the image should be in the bottom corners of the view. The height of it must remain the same though.

[image]

Here is the XML I have so far.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/landscape"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_gallery_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_tralee_header_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:src="@drawable/infromationpage_alliance_banner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, is there a way to resize images in XML? When I try to resize e.g. the top in by dragging its corners, the image doesnt resize with the Layout. Does it mean I have to make the images smaller? Seems like a lot of work to make each image exactly the right size. Is there a way to do this programatically in XML or java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try taking

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

of the main RelativeLayout.

However, you will then need to add

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

to each row your want to have the padding, or put them all in their own Layout and just add the padding to that.